# Dynamic structure <td> and the value of property

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

1) how to add a loop for the dynamic determination of the sum of td by the sum of th

2) @ key = 'ip' - it is also necessary to make dynamic that would take a value from the constructed t

```
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Type</th>
  <th>Text</th>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="//folder/element/property" group-by="@key">
    <th><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></th>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="@*[name() = 'xsi:type'][1]"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="documentation"/>
  </td>
  <xsl:for-each select="...">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="string-join(property[@key='ip']/@value, ', ')"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:for-each>
</tr>
```

input xml file

```
<folder name="Technology &amp; Physical" type="technology">
    <element xsi:type="archimate:Node" name="SMX_U_TEST">
      <documentation>SMX</documentation>
      <property key="ip" value="10.255.2.111"/>
    </element>
    <element xsi:type="archimate:Node" name="CBS3CVR">
      <documentation>DSR3CVR</documentation>
      <property key="ip" value="10.15.114.24"/>
      <property key="port" value="1521"/>
      <property key="hw"/>
    </element>
    <element xsi:type="archimate:Node" name="SMX">
      <property key="ip" value="10.255.2.111"/>
      <property key="port" value="8181"/>
      <property key="port" value="8182"/>
      <property key="port" value="8184"/>
    </element>
    <element xsi:type="archimate:Node" name="Informatica test">
       <documentation>Informatica</documentation>
      <property key="ip" value="10.11.30.89"/>
      <property key="port" value="1521"/>
    </element>
    <element xsi:type="archimate:Node" name="DSR3TEST">
      <documentation>DSR3TEST</documentation>
      <property key="ip" value="10.255.3.133"/>
      <property key="port" value="1521"/>
      <property key="hw"/>
    </element>
</folder>
```

outout html file

```
<html xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <body>
      <h2>Technology &amp; Physical</h2>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Text</th>
            <th>ip</th>
            <th>port</th>
            <th>hw</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>CBS3CVR</td>
            <td>archimate:Node</td>
            <td>DSR3CVR</td>
            <td>10.15.114.24</td>
            <td>1521</td>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>DSR3TEST</td>
            <td>archimate:Node</td>
            <td>DSR3TEST</td>
            <td>10.255.3.133</td>
            <td>1521</td>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Informatica test</td>
            <td>archimate:Node</td>
            <td>Informatica</td>
            <td>10.11.30.89</td>
            <td>1521</td>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>SMX</td>
            <td>archimate:Node</td>
            <td/>
            <td>10.255.2.111</td>
            <td>8181, 8182, 8184</td>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>SMX_U_TEST</td>
            <td>archimate:Node</td>
            <td>SMX</td>
            <td>10.255.2.111</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </body>
  </html>
```

The number of element and property is unlimited, and the name of the keys may be different.
I used group by, if you have another decided, tell me. thank you!!!

Comment: I do not understand the question, maybe add an example to illustrate your goals.

Comment: We do really need to see a sample of your input XML, and your expected output, to give a precise answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `distinct-values` here to get the distinct `property` keys, rather than `xsl:for-each-group`

```
<xsl:variable name="properties" select="distinct-values(element/property/@key)" />
```

(This is assuming you are positioned on the `folder` element).

Then, for each `element` in your XML, you can list the values of the properties like so

```
<xsl:variable name="current" select="." />
<xsl:for-each select="$properties">
<td>
  <xsl:value-of select="$current/property[@key=current()]/@value" separator=", " />
</td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               exclude-result-prefixes="xsi">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="folder">
        <xsl:variable name="properties" select="distinct-values(element/property/@key)" />
        <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Text</th>
              <xsl:for-each select="$properties">
                <th><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="element">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@xsi:type"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="documentation"/>
              </td>
              <xsl:variable name="current" select="." />
              <xsl:for-each select="$properties">
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$current/property[@key=current()]/@value" separator=", " />
                </td>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have assumed your actual XML does declare the `xsi` namespace prefix. I also declare it in the XSLT to make retrieving `xsl:type` attribute simpler.

EDIT: If you can only use an XSLT 1.0 processor, you won't be able to use `distinct-values` to get get the keys. Instead you would need to make use of a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to get the distinct keys. (You also wouldn't be able to use the `separator` attribute on `xsl:value-of`).

Try this XSLT instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               exclude-result-prefixes="xsi">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="properties" match="property" use="@key" />

    <xsl:template match="folder">
        <xsl:variable name="properties" select="//property[generate-id() = generate-id(key('properties', @key)[1])]/@key" />
        <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Text</th>
              <xsl:for-each select="$properties">
                <th><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="element">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@xsi:type"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="documentation"/>
              </td>
              <xsl:variable name="current" select="." />
              <xsl:for-each select="$properties">
                <td>
                  <xsl:for-each select="$current/property[@key=current()]/@value">
                    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: what is the `xsl:template match="@*|node()"` for?

Comment: and `properties` is not array

Comment: The `xsl:template match="@*|node()` was the identity template, but it was not needed in this instance so I have removed it. You are correct that the `properties` variable is not an array, as XSLT has no concept of arrays. The `distinct-values` function actually returns a sequence (See http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_distinct-values.html)

Comment: It turns out I had a debugger 1.0 version. Thank you!

Comment: Translate to the xsl 2.0 version it will be difficult?

Comment: The XSLT in my answer requires an XSLT 2.0 processor. If you do not have one, you would need to convert it to XSLT 1.0. I have made an edit to my answer to show this. See it in action at http://xsltransform.net/gVhD8Rv